# Regex match string beginning with ?code=

Tags: python, regex, django, django-views, django-urls

I'm using python and django to match urls for my site. I need to match a url that looks like this:
/company/code/?code=34k3593d39k

The part after ?code= is any combination of letters and numbers, and any length.

I've tried this so far:

```
r'^company/code/(.+)/$'
r'^company/code/(\w+)/$'
r'^company/code/(\D+)/$'
r'^company/code/(.*)/$'
```

But so far none are catching the expression. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`code=34k3593d39k` is `GET` parameter and you don't need to define the pattern for it in URL pattern. You can access it using `request.GET.get('code')` under view. The pattern should be just:

```
r'^company/code/$'
```

Usage, accessing GET parameter:

```
def my_view(request):
    code = request.GET.get('code')
    print code
```

Check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#what-the-urlconf-searches-against):

> The URLconf searches against the requested URL, as a normal Python
>   string. This does not include GET or POST parameters, or the domain
>   name.

Comment: Should it be code = request.GET.get("code")? Because I'm getting an UnboundLocalError, where I reference code before it's assigned

Comment: @user3749797 Yes a simple typo.

Answer (score 1):

The first pattern will work if you move the last `/` to just after the `^`:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r'^/company/code/(.+)$', '/company/code/?code=34k3593d39k')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0209C4A0>
>>> re.match(r'^/company/code/(.+)$', '/company/code/?code=34k3593d39k').groups()
('?code=34k3593d39k',)
>>>
```

Note too that the `^` is unnecessary because `re.match` matches from the start of the string:

```
>>> re.match(r'/company/code/(.+)$', '/company/code/?code=34k3593d39k').groups()
('?code=34k3593d39k',)
>>>
```